# Rails data management best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations

I have a situation with an app I am currently working with and I am unsure how to proceed going forward.

In order to test certain models (reports) we need production-level data - both initial set-up data (a survey) and user data (a user's answers to a survey, sometimes more than one user). The initial data is created using a script in the production environment to load the data in to the application. In our feature tests we need to do this exact same thing (or have a reasonably close facsimile to it) and then fake some user data (known answers in order to test report calculations and structure).

What I am struggling with is how to manage the initial data. As development progresses this data may change and I would rather not be managing this in multiple locations (a script for initial load, migrations for production changes, factories/fixtures to make sure the data loaded in to a test reflects what is currently live etc.). Are there any best practice resources for this? Should fixtures be used for the initial load from the script and can then be used by the tests? Do I just load the script to create the initial-data from my tests? I have read that data migrations are bad and we are attempting to avoid them but how do I handle that in a multi-developer environment where the script I create may not be executed by the developer doing the release (capistrano).

Thoughts? Questions, comments, concerns?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Migrations are a bit annoying, but they're needed for schema based databases.

If you're not querying on these fields, then you can save a column as JSON with many different data.

If you wanna go even further, they a schema-less database such as MongoDB. I use MongoDB myself with the Mongoid gem, it works just like activerecord.